# UIPickerView with Conditions

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am completely new to Xcode and anything really to do with coding but I am winging it and seem to be doing ok until now.  What I want to do...

I have a `UIPickerView` that has 2 components populated by an array.  It's fine and works lovely but I wish to take this one step further.

On the left-hand component, I wish to have a list with constant values that never change.  In the second component, I wish to have a sublist of whatever selection that has been clicked on in the first component.

For Example:-

```
BOY : Matt
      Tom
      Pete

GIRL : Jess
       Nina
       Sarah
```

I figured I could use an `if` statement to get these changes to happen BUT not knowing the language... there is only so much trial and error one guy can take !

Cheers

```
@interface TripsViewController ()
@end

@implementation TripsViewController

@synthesize ActivitysLabel;
@synthesize TripsLabel;

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == ACTIVITY)
        return [ArrayActivity count];

    if (component == TRIPS)
        return [ArrayTrips count];

    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if (component == ACTIVITY)
        return [ArrayActivity objectAtIndex:row];

    if (component == TRIPS)
        return [ArrayTrips objectAtIndex:row];
    return 0;
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    ActivitysLabel.text = [ArrayActivity objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    TripsLabel.text = [ArrayTrips objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ArrayActivity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"Abseiling"];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"Canyoning"];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"Rock Climbing"];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"Bush Walking"];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"Mountain Biking"];
    [ArrayActivity addObject:@"4wd Tours"];


    // My attempts at trying to solve this problem


    if (ArrayActivity containsObject:NSString @"Canyoning") {
        ArrayTrips = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [ArrayTrips addObject:@"Empress Canyon"];
        [ArrayTrips addObject:@"Sheep Dip"];
        [ArrayTrips addObject:@"butterbox"];
    }
```

Comment: Or could someone send me a link if this has been answered somewhere else. Really want to sort this problem out.

Answer (score 0):

The code I think is generally correct, but what you must do after picking the item that will alter possible selections, is call `reloadComponent` with the index of the column where the data is different.  Do that right after a new entry is selected (make sure to only trigger the reload on the correct component selection).